# Showing ouput generated from an ajax request into a html div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am working on a form on which I want to show the records related to the value user selects from the combo box and show them all into a `<div>` so I wrote down my code but the problem is that the request is being transferred to the external file, but it is not showing the output.

Here is my code:

```
$("#tag_header").change(function(){
    if($("#tag_header>option:selected").val() !==""){
        $("#brand_name").removeAttr("readonly",false);
        $("#brand_name").css("background", "white");    
        var tagid = $("#tag_header>option:selected").val() ;
        $.get("view_product_dtl.php?tag_header="+tagid,function(result){ 
            $("#grid").html(data);
        });
    }else{
        $("#brand_name").attr("readonly",true);
        $("#brand_name").css("background", "#C0C0C0");  
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the success event, you refer to the `data` variable, but your response is in `result` not `data`. Change to:

```
$("#grid").html(result);
```

---

A minor improvement would be to use an object to pass the `tagid` instead of concatenating. The benefit of this is that jQuery will automatically handle the URL encoding of the value.

```
$.get("view_product_dtl.php", { tag_header : tagid }, function(result){ 
    $("#grid").html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback uses `result` not `data`

```
$.get("view_product_dtl.php?tag_header="+tagid,function(result){ 
    //$("#grid").html(data);
    $("#grid").html(result);
});
```